# Create a tuple out of two columns - PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, zip, pyspark

My problem is based on the similar question here [PySpark: Add a new column with a tuple created from columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067861/pyspark-add-a-new-column-with-a-tuple-created-from-columns), with the difference that I have a list of values instead of one value per column. For example:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(v1=[u'2.0', u'1.0', u'9.0'], v2=[u'9.0', u'7.0', u'2.0']),Row(v1=[u'4.0', u'8.0', u'9.0'], v2=[u'1.0', u'1.0', u'2.0'])])

    +---------------+---------------+
    |             v1|             v2|
    +---------------+---------------+
    |[2.0, 1.0, 9.0]|[9.0, 7.0, 2.0]|
    |[2.0, 1.0, 9.0]|[9.0, 7.0, 2.0]|
    +---------------+---------------+
```

What I am trying to get is something similar like zip element-wise for the lists per row, but I cant figure it out in pyspark 1.6:

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
|             v1|             v2|             v_tuple|
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
|[2.0, 1.0, 9.0]|[9.0, 7.0, 2.0]|[(2.0,9.0), (1.0,...|
|[4.0, 8.0, 9.0]|[1.0, 1.0, 2.0]|[(4.0,1.0), (8.0,...|
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Note: The size of the arrays may vary from row to row, but it is always the same for the same row column-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If size of the arrays varies from row to row you'll need and UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf("array<struct<_1:double,_2:double>>")
def zip_(xs, ys):
    return list(zip(xs, ys))

df.withColumn("v_tuple", zip_("v1", "v2"))
```

In Spark 1.6:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

zip_ = udf(
    lambda xs, ys: list(zip(xs, ys)),
    ArrayType(StructType([StructField("_1", DoubleType()), StructField("_2", DoubleType())])))
```