# Unzip a list of tuples - PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I asked the reverse question here [Create a tuple out of two columns - PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940270/create-a-tuple-out-of-two-columns-pyspark/45941937#45941937). What I am trying to do now is unzip a list of tuples located in a dataframe column, into two different lists per row. So based on the dataframe below, v_tuple column back to v1 and v2.

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
|             v1|             v2|             v_tuple|
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
|[2.0, 1.0, 9.0]|[9.0, 7.0, 2.0]|[(2.0,9.0), (1.0,...|
|[4.0, 8.0, 9.0]|[1.0, 1.0, 2.0]|[(4.0,1.0), (8.0,...|
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Based on my previous column I tried the following without success:

```
unzip_ = udf(
    lambda l: list(zip(*l)),
    ArrayType(ArrayType("_1", DoubleType()), ArrayType("_2", DoubleType())))
```

I am using pyspark 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode you're array and then group it back again:

First let's create our dataframe:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize([
            [[2.0, 1.0, 9.0], [9.0, 7.0, 2.0], [(2.0,9.0), (1.0,7.), (9.,2.)]],
            [[4.0, 8.0, 9.0], [1.0, 1.0, 2.0], [(4.0,1.0), (8.0,1.), (9., 2.)]]
        ]), 
    ["v1", "v2", "v_tuple"] 
)
```

Let's add a row id to identify it uniquely:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df = df.withColumn("id", psf.monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Now, we can explode column "v_tuple" and create two columns from the two elements of the tuple:

```py
df = df.withColumn("v_tuple", psf.explode("v_tuple")).select(
    "id", 
    psf.col("v_tuple._1").alias("v1"), 
    psf.col("v_tuple._2").alias("v2")
)

    +-----------+---+---+
    |         id| v1| v2|
    +-----------+---+---+
    |42949672960|2.0|9.0|
    |42949672960|1.0|7.0|
    |42949672960|9.0|2.0|
    |94489280512|4.0|1.0|
    |94489280512|8.0|1.0|
    |94489280512|9.0|2.0|
    +-----------+---+---+
```

Finally, we can group it back again:

```py
df = df.groupBy("id").agg(
    psf.collect_list("v1").alias("v1"),
    psf.collect_list("v2").alias("v2")
)

    +-----------+---------------+---------------+
    |         id|             v1|             v2|
    +-----------+---------------+---------------+
    |42949672960|[2.0, 1.0, 9.0]|[9.0, 7.0, 2.0]|
    |94489280512|[4.0, 8.0, 9.0]|[1.0, 1.0, 2.0]|
    +-----------+---------------+---------------+
```